# Best practice when calling initialize functions multiple times?

Tags: c++, error-handling, initialization

This may be a subjective question, but I'm more or less asking it and hoping that people share their experiences. (As that is the biggest thing which I lack in C++)

Anyways, suppose I have -for some obscure reason- an initialize function that initializes a datastructure from the heap:

```
void initialize() {
    initialized = true;
    pointer = new T;
}
```

now When I would call the initialize function twice, an memory leak would happen (right?). So I can prevent this is multiple ways:

- ignore the call (just check wether I am initialized, and if I am don't do anything)
- Throw an error
- automatically "cleanup" the code and then reinitialize the thing.

Now what is generally the "best" method, which helps keeping my code manegeable in the future?

**EDIT**: thank you for the answers so far. However I'd like to know how people handle this is a more generic way. - How do people handle "simple" errors which **can** be ignored. (like, calling the same function twice while only 1 time it makes sense).

Answer (score 4):

You're the only one who can truly answer the question : do you consider that the `initialize` function *could eventually* be called twice, or would this mean that your program followed an unexpected execution flow ?

- If the `initialize` function can be called multiple times : just ignore the call by testing if the allocation has already taken place.
- If the `initialize` function has no decent reason to be called several times : I believe that would be a good candidate for an exception.

Just to be clear, I don't believe *cleanup and regenerate* to be a viable option (or you should seriously consider renaming the function to reflect this behavior).

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is not unusual for *on-demand* or *lazy initialization* of costly data structures that might not always be needed.  Singleton is one example, or for a class data member that meets those criteria.

What I would do is just skip the init code if the struct is already in place.

```
void initialize() {
    if (!initialized)
    {
      initialized = true;
      pointer = new T;
    }
}
```

If your program has multiple threads you would have to include locking to make this thread-safe.

Comment: @kotlinski, sure, especially if the init logic was more extensive than in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using boost or STL smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends entirely on `T` (and other members of this class). If they are lightweight and there is no side-effect of re-creating a new one, then by all means cleanup and re-create (but use smart pointers). If on the other hand they are heavy (say a network connection or something like that), you should simply bypass if the boolean is set...

You should also investigate `boost::optional`, this way you don't need an overall flag, and for each object that should exist, you can check to see if instantiated and then instantiate as necessary... (say in the first pass, some construct okay, but some fail..)

Answer (score 0):

The idea of setting a data member later than the constructor is quite common, so don't worry you're definitely not the first one with this issue.

There are two typical use cases:

- On demand / Lazy instantiation: if you're not sure it will be used and it's costly to create, then better NOT to initialize it in the constructor
- Caching data: to cache the result of a potentially expensive operation so that subsequent calls need not compute it once again

You are in the "Lazy" category, in which case the simpler way is to use a flag or a nullable value:

- flag + value combination: reuse of existing class without heap allocation, however this requires default construction
- smart pointer: this bypass the default construction issue, at the cost of heap allocation. Check the copy semantics you need...
- `boost::optional<T>`: similar to a pointer, but with deep copy semantics and no heap allocation. Requires the type to be fully defined though, so heavier on dependencies.

I would strongly recommend the `boost::optional<T>` idiom, or if you wish to provide dependency insulation you might fall back to a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<T>` (or `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` if you do not have access to a C++0x compiler).

Answer (score -1):

I think that this could be a scenario where the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern could be applied.

Comment: the singleton isn't a solution here, the OP does not indicate that only a *single instance* exists, merely that his `initialize()` method is called multiple times...

Comment: since he has to avoid multiple initialization, to me singleton does apply.